# implement wpf gridview as same in the Metro style gridview

Tags: wpf, gridview, wpf-controls, microsoft-metro, wpfdatagrid

For my WPF application i'm trying to get windows 8 metro Gridview style in WPF. Here is my sample code of metro style Gridview design:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DashboardItemTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600" Height="120">
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="#4B0F03">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#000000">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"     Height="70" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DashboardItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>
```

But I didn't get any options for binding DataTemplate in WPF Gridview, is there any option available to bind Gridview with DataTemplate in WPF application? or Any other way to get WPF Gridview like windows 8 Gridview style.